# Selection sort algorithm in java isn't working properly

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, selection-sort

I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong in this code. It's a practice problem from school. The **TODO** was given to guide us on what we have to do towards solving the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SelectionSort<E> extends AbstractSortingStrategy<E> {

public SelectionSort(Comparator<E> cmp) { 
    super("SelectionSort", cmp); 
}

@Override
public void sortList(ArrayList<E> dataSet) {
    int n = dataSet.size(); 

    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int smallest = (int) dataSet.get(i);
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if(cmp.compare(dataSet.get(j), dataSet.get(smallest)) < 0) {
                smallest = (int) dataSet.get(j);
            }
            SortingUtils.swapListElements(dataSet, smallest, i);
        }
    }

    /* TODO ADD CODE HERE FOLLOWING PSEUDOCODE
     * 
     * Use a simple for loop to find the smallest value in the desired range
     * 
     * To compare two values in dataSet, use something like:
     *    if (cmp.compare(dataSet.get(j), dataSet.get(sm)) < 0)
     * To swap, use something like:
     *    SortingUtils.swapListElements(dataSet, sm, i); 
     *    assuming that sm and i are indexes within dataSet.
     */
    }
}
```

Comment: Change this ->>>> int smallest = (int) dataSet.get(i); to this -----> int smallest = i

Comment: That didn't fix it, the list is still unordered. Thanks though. @RohitSuthar

Comment: also change this  -----> smallest = (int) dataSet.get(j); to this 
smallest = j;

Comment: Also changed that when I saw your first comment, still not working. @RohitSuthar

Comment: Ohh Got it just move swapping line out of the inner loop

Comment: Move this line             SortingUtils.swapListElements(dataSet, smallest, i);
outside of the inner loop

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much. The list was almost sorted, but there was always 2 or 3 numbers that weren't sorted. Appreciate your help! @RohitSuthar